# Node JS: Response does not get changed even after changing the url

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying login into `teeSpring.com` then get the response from another url using login cookie. When anybody login in to teeSpring.com, it returns the dashboard details.
But whenever I am trying to `GET` second url, teeSpring returns me same dashboard details.
 If I hit both urls in Chrome's REST client, it comes back different responses which is expected.
Then what is the issue with my requests?

> > Note: If anyone needed username/password for testing please let me know.

Here is code:

```
var http = require('http'),
    express = require('express'),
    request = require('request');

var request = request.defaults({jar:true});

app.post('/login', [express.urlencoded(), express.json()], function(req, res) {
    request.post({
      url: 'http://teeSpring.com/login/submitLogin',
      form: {
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
      }
    }, function(error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
        res.send(400, "There is some problem  here.");  
      } else if(response) {
        if(response.statusCode == 302 && response.headers && response.headers.location) {         
          request.get('http://analytics.teeSpring.com', function(error, response, analyticsBody){
            if(!this.error && this.response.statusCode==200) {
              res.send(analyticsBody);
            }
          });
        }
      } else {
        console.log('WTF');
      }

    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but try renaming the GET callback function parameters `error` and `response`. It depends if you are using strict mode or not, but the same variable names might or might not come to effect (even if using this)..

Comment: No luck. Still the same issue.

Comment: Can you debug your node.js code? Set a breakpoint on row `res.send(analyticsBody);` Is the `analyticsBody` really equal to `body` ?

Comment: Strangely `body` is empty but `analyticsBody` has content which should be in `body`.

Comment: My guess is your GET request is not using the authentication token returned in POST (login) return value. Should the `request` class automatically handle this for you? If not, you should add the authentication information, from POST call return value, to GET request.

Comment: @supertopi the cookies are supposed to be handled by `request` (see the examples of https://github.com/mikeal/request). @Himanshu Yadav: Are you sure that the POST request sets cookies?

Comment: I am using `var request = request.defaults({jar:true});`. If I remove it, teeSpring server returns `Login` page back which happens on the browser too.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Gist on Github with some code: https://gist.github.com/Stofkn/11397460

Just replace the require('supertest') with require('superagent').
https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent

With this module it's easy to attach the cookie to your requests.

Basically you need to attach the cookie you received from the POST request so that you're autherized for the GET request.

The lines are important:

```
function saveCookies (res) {
  agent.saveCookies(res);
}
```

Send POST and GET request (saving cookie is done in request.js):

```
request
  .post('/login')
  .send(formData)
  .end(function (err, res) {
    request
      .get('/test') 
      .end(function (err, res) {
         // some code        
       });
   });
```

Also change the path that I use in the request.js file. In your case you can't give a baseurl because they are different.

I hope this will fix your issue!